# <head> must start with [charset] - A11Y HTML5 Validator

Tags: html, vuejs3, accessibility, vite, charset

I use vite, vue3 and  A11Y HTML5 Validator Chrome ispector
While inspecting A11Y HTML5 Validator, <head> must start with [charset] error is displayed continuously.

[image]

in index.html code
`<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />`

Commenting out the code makes that error go away.
I don't know what could be the reason.
my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=5.0"
    />
    <title>web title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
...
```

delete `<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />` code
working but I don't know why

Once the problem is solved I wonder why

Comment: Your code looks fine, could be an issue with the extension

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input only warns about trailing slashes, no errors

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for `<link>`